# Synthetic division versus direct substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Why is it that I was taught to perform synthetic division to verify roots when I could much more easily perform direct substitution?  I know synthetic division gives me the resulting polynomial after factoring out the root, but I can easily do that *after* I've verified a certain root will work.

Is there some secret message I didn't get?  Or is it arguably easier?

P.S. This is usually used when we are taught the rational roots theorem and we are told to use synthetic division to verify which of the possible roots work.  So... lot's and lot's of synthetic division...

Comment: I'm with you, and certainly I would never have taught students to do the drudgery of dividing by every possible linear factor to test for roots. Of course you should substitute, and then apply the root-factor theorem to see what the quotient will be.

Comment: I think it's easier if you just substitute...

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the comment.  Was just going over some frustrating memories and remembering I was so confused over this topic.